# Git can't clone from github

Tags: git, github, ubuntu-20.04

I am trying to clone from github but it I am getting this error

```
git clone https://github.com/angular/angular.git
```

> fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/angular/angular.git/': Operation timed out after 300031 milliseconds with 0 out of 0 bytes received

While ping looks working

```
ping github.com
```

> PING github.com (13.234.176.102) 56(84) bytes of data.
> 64 bytes from ec2-13-234-176-102.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com (13.234.176.102): icmp_seq=1 ttl=43 time=35.0 ms

And clone from gitlab is working fine, I face this issue only with github

Any idea how I can solve this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Works fine for me, are you behind any corporate proxies or firewalls?

Comment: ping and git clone don't use the same protocol. Maybe a firewall is blocking https request to github?

Comment: no, and it is working if I clone from gitlab, only it is not working with gihub @jonrsharpe

Comment: I just installed a fresh copy of ubuntu 20.04 and git, how can i make sure there is no firewall? @LeoG.

Comment: is this a virtual ubuntu machine? Is it on a corporate server or behind a VPN/Proxy of some kind? How are you connected to the internet?

Answer (score 0):

To disable the firewall in Ubuntu, enter the following command,

`sudo ufw disable`

and to enable the firewall again, enter the following command,

`sudo ufw enable`

Comment: I have disabled the firewall, but it is still the same issue

Comment: I see you are using an EC2 instance on AWS, can you check if HTTPS, HTTP and SSH on the outgoing security groups, for the EC2 instance are applied.